# Porque ao importar dados com o Pandas as vírgulas dos números estão sendo apagadas?

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping

Estou quebrando a cabeça para entender o motivo disso acontecer ao pegar os dados numéricos de uma tabela na web. Nesta tabela contêm os valores de cotações das moedas, o problema ocorre que, ao pegar os valores numéricos, todas as virgulas que separavam os valores em centavos desaparecem, este é o código que estou fazendo

```
option = Options()
option.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=option)

driver.get(url)
time.sleep(10)

elemento = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="wrapper"]//section//table[@id="exchange_rates_1"]')
html_content = elemento.get_attribute('outerHTML')

#2 - Parsear o conteúdo HTML - BeautiFulSouap
souap = BeautifulSoup(html_content, 'html.parser')
table = souap.find(name='table')
print(table)

#3 - Estruturar conteúdos em um Data Frame - Pandas
df_full = pd.read_html(str(table))[0]
df = df_full[['Código', 'BRL']]
df.columns = ['Moeda', 'Perante_Real']

print(df_full)
print(df)



driver.quit()
```

Não compreendo o motivo, mas acredito que esteja nessa linha

> df_full = pd.read_html(str(table))[0]

Pois antes disso, no meio da bagunça do código HTML importado estava tudo certo com os valores numéricos.  Se alguém puder ajudar agradeço!

Answer (score 1):

Quando voce utiliza o "read_html" voce pode setar atributos que definem os valores numericos conforme demonstrado em [https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html?highlight=read_html#pandas.read_html] , um destes input é o parametro "decimal" que como padrão está setado para um "." , dependendo da formatacao do site (html) , este pode ser uma vírgula, tente o codigo com a seguinte alteração desta linha

df_full = pd.read_html(str(table),decimal=',')[0]

caso nao tenha sucesso, por favor poste um print(df_full.head(5)) ou print(df.head(5)) para que eu possa ver como está a formatação dos dados no df.

Comment: Eu fiz a alteração mas não mudou em nada, esse é o  resultado do print 
`Moeda  Perante_Real
0   BRL             1
1   USD         53411
2   EUR         59976
3   GBP         66558
4   JPY          4963`

As moedas não estão separadas em virgulas

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver assim `df_full = pd.read_html(str(table).replace(',', '.'))[0]` 
Provavelmente não estava reconhecendo a virgula no meio dos números mesmo!